# Logical AND ,OR CAML Query not working in External List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using ClientContext Class and CAML query to retrieve items from External List in sharepoint 2010.I have built the query with Logical AND Condition in CAML Query like this

```
 string sDataFilter =<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Year" /><Value Type="Text">1960</Value></Eq><Contains><FieldRef Name="ChartName" /><Value Type="Text">Chart1</Value></Contains></And></Where></Query>
```

When I exceute the following code

```
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(list));
               CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
               string queryContext = "<View><Query>" + sDataFilter + "</Query>" + viewFieldsContext + "</View>";
               camlQuery.ViewXml = queryContext;
               ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
               clientContext.Load(collListItem);
               clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am getting the empty ListItemCollection.I have cross verified with the **U2U CAML Query Builder** the data is empty only. So in External List the caml query is working fine for sorting and simple filter query like Where,EqualTo condition I can't use Logical conditions in the query ? If yes how could I achieve this using caml query
Could anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: what is your `sDataFilter ` and `viewFieldsContext `? can you plz declare over here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is below line of code

```
   string queryContext = "<View><Query>" + sDataFilter + "</Query>" + viewFieldsContext + "</View>";
```

change this line with follwing code

```
  string queryContext = "<View>" + sDataFilter +  viewFieldsContext + "</View>";
```

the problem is in Query tag. It's two time repeat in query.
late me know when it's working

Thax